# Динамически скрыть item menu

Tags: android, menu

В `layout.xml` на *чекбоксе* есть событие `onclick`, которое обрабатывается в `main activity`.

Нужно по нажатию *чекбокса* показать элемент верхнего меню *ActionBar*.

Как это сделать?

Пробую `findViewById(...)`, потом `visible(true)`, но скомпилировать с такими изменениями не получается.

Comment: Уточните что имеется ввиду под элементом верхнего меню? Элемент из ActionBar

Comment: Извините, не уточнил, да - это ActionBar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private MenuItem logoutMI;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    logoutMI = menu.add(0, 1, 0,"Logout").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logout);
    logoutMI.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    logoutMI.setVisible(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

---

```
logoutMI.setVisible(true);
```

*а если, в menu > main.xml*

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    logoutMI = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: а если, в menu > main.xml прописаны item'ы?
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete_msg"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
</menu>

Comment: @aliokero обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, что помогли разобраться